# Blank page when using newlfm and pdfpages

Tags: pdfpages, newlfm

I am using `newlfm` for a document and am also loading `pdfpages` to append some external PDF files to the end of this document.  My problem is that I get a blank page at the end of the document, traceable to `newlfm`.  If I omit the `{newlfm}` environment the blank page disappears -- but of course that environment is necessary in order for the documentclass to format the page properly.

Here is a MWE:

**external.tex****:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
This is an external file.
\end{document}
```

**wrapper.tex****:

```
\documentclass{newlfm}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
\begin{newlfm}
This is a nicely formatted introductory page.
\includepdf{external.pdf}
\end{newlfm}
\end{document}
```

The above produces a three-page `wrapper.pdf`, when it should contain only two pages.

Can anyone help?

**UPDATE**

Per @jon's request, here is a second MWE that illustrates the header problem when the inclusion of the PDF is invoked outside the `newlfm` environment:

**wrapper2.tex****:

```
\documentclass[stdletternofrom]{newlfm}
\Lheader{Left Header}
\lheader{second-page left header}
\Rheader{Page \thepage}
\rheader{Page \thepage}

\usepackage{pdfpages}

\newcounter{includepdfpage}
\newcounter{currentpagecounter}
\newcommand{\addlabelstoallincludedpages}[1]{%
   \refstepcounter{includepdfpage}%
   \stepcounter{currentpagecounter}%
   \label{#1.\thecurrentpagecounter}}
\newcommand{\modifiedincludepdf}[2]{%
        \includepdf[pages=-,pagecommand=\addlabelstoallincludedpages{#1}]{#2}%
}
\begin{document}
\begin{newlfm}
This is a nicely formatted introductory page.
\modifiedincludepdf{ExtFile}{external.pdf}
\end{newlfm}
\end{document}
```

If `\end{newlfm}` is moved above `\modifiedincludepdf`, instead of the second-page header appearing on Page 2, the first-page header is there and is in the wrong location.

Comment: Can't you just switch the order of `\includepdf{external.pdf}` and `\end{newlfm}`?

Comment: @jon:  No, I had already tried that; it messes with the page headers invoked by the `pagecommand` option of `\includepdf` (not shown in the MWE for the sake of brevity).

Comment: Ah, well, then we need a fuller 'minimal working example' (and maybe description of what the desired output is).  That is, what page headers do you need and where?

Comment: @jon: See updated question with more extensive MWE.

Comment: Sorry, I can't explain the interaction between the two, especially since I've never really used or liked `newlfm`.  My quick solution would be to use [pdftk](http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/) and just cut away the offending page, but it might be worth bringing to the attention of the `newlfm` author if no one answers here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes Brian, I reproduced your problem while using `newlfm`. Luckily, in your case, as long as you issue a `\AtBeginShipout\AtBeginShipoutDiscard` right after the `<filename.pdf>`, it fixes the problem.

In the past, I noticed the `newlfm` package has serious issues with these extra pages, that unfortunately, even after issuing a `\clearpage` simply do not resolve the issue.

So, say for example, and  only for demonstration purposes, a pdf file is created by:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\begin{document}
\kant[1-5]
\end{document}
```

Then a total of 2 pages are created. But when you include the above file in your MWE, an unwanted page results, if you don't issue `\AtBeginShipout\AtBeginShipoutDiscard`

The following is the correct solution. Please note that the option `pages=-`, was used, as the `pdfpages` manual states, so all the pages that resulted from the aforementioned file, are included in the document.

```
\documentclass[]{newlfm}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}
\begin{newlfm}
This is a nicely formatted introductory page.
\includepdf[pages=-]{akantsample.pdf}\AtBeginShipout\AtBeginShipoutDiscard
\end{newlfm}
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Anytime! Glad it worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

As far as your mock documents go, this works well enough:

**External file:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
This is an external file.
\end{document}
```

**Main file:**

```
\documentclass{newlfm}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
\begin{newlfm}
This is a nicely formatted introductory page.
\end{newlfm}
\includepdf{external.pdf}
\end{document}
```

I get a one page letter followed by the other `.tex` file (two pages total).

Comment: See my updated question for an example of why this doesn't solve my problem.