# pdfpages produces additional blank pages and \AtBeginShipout\AtBeginShipoutDiscard doesn't fix

Tags: pdfpages, blank-page

I am trying to include twice an A5 landscape PDF with `pdfpages`.  Unfortunately
I get a bunch of blank pages. Here is MWE.

```
\documentclass[A4paper,final]{minimal}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\includepdf[nup=1x2,doublepages=true,pages=-]{imposed-nup.pdf}
\end{document}
```

Here [`imposed-nup.pdf`](http://kde35.free.fr/files/imposed-nup.pdf) is a two-page A5 landscape document, and one would expect to get an A4 document of two pages.  However, `pdflatex` produces a document of seven pages!  Using `\AtBeginShipout\AtBeginShipoutDiscard` suggested as in [this page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/91087/blank-page-when-using-newlfm-and-pdfpages) removes two blank pages out of five, but I still get three blank pages.

The `.log` says, among other things,

```
<imposed-nup.pdf, id=1, 845.0471pt x 597.50829pt>
File: imposed-nup.pdf Graphic file (type pdf)
 <use imposed-nup.pdf>
Package pdftex.def Info: imposed-nup.pdf used on input line 6.
(pdftex.def)             Requested size: 845.04504pt x 597.50682pt.
```

so I suspect the fact that the fact that the page size of the included PDF is "too large" is causing the problem. I tried `templatesize` option but it didn't fix the issue. Any idea on how to get around this problem?

Comment: please try with `\documentclass[a4paper,final]{article}`

Comment: and see [why-should-the-minimal-class-be-avoided](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42114/why-should-the-minimal-class-be-avoided)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you should use it:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\includepdf[nup=1x2,doublepages=true,pages=-]{imposed-nup.pdf}
\end{document}
```

The differences are:

- The `\documentclass` should be `article`, not `minimal`. See [Why should the `minimal` class be avoided?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/42114/5764)
- The paper size (now that you're using `article`) should be `a4paper`, not `A4paper`;